# ggplot2 scale_fill_gradientn is ignoring specified colours and returning black and white plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I'm trying to plot the differences in amplitude of a signal using a fill gradient to picture the changes in amplitude across different locations in a head map. The original code was taken from this wonderful [site](http://www.mattcraddock.com/blog/2017/02/25/erp-visualization-creating-topographical-scalp-maps-part-1/) on ERP visualization.

The problem I encounter is that, although the colour gradient is defined in  scale_fill_gradientn() and it should depend on the amplitude value, the program is ignoring it and returning a black and white plot. Note that the contour, which is also dependent of amplitude, is there. The only thing missing is the colour. I have tried changing the limits and the number of jet.colors at play, but the figure that I get is still black and white. I have also checked that the colour functionality is OK and tested with other type of graphics and the colour works fine there.

[image]

My guess is that it has something to do whit the amplitude values in my data. In case it's useful, my amplitude column is a set of 836 (unique) continuous values ranging from -24.57 to 40.57.

Thanks in advance!

---

```
myPlot <- ggplot(interpTopo,
aes(x = x, y = y, fill = amplitude)
) +
geom_raster() +
stat_contour(aes(z = amplitude),
           colour = "black",
           binwidth = 0.5) +
theme_topo()+
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = jet.colors(10),
                   limits = c(-45,45),
                   guide = "colourbar",
                   oob = squish) + 
geom_path(data = maskRing,
        aes(x, y, z = NULL, fill =NULL),
        colour = "white",
        size = 6)+
geom_point(data = myData,
         aes(x, y),
         size = 1)+
geom_path(data = headShape,
        aes(x, y, z = NULL, fill = NULL),
        size = 1.5)+
geom_path(data = nose,
        aes(x, y, z = NULL, fill = NULL),
        size = 1.5)+
coord_equal()
```

myPlot

**EDIT**

I've averaged my data across participants and hence reduced notably the size of the data frame to make it more manageable.
The data frame interptopo is used for the interpolation of amplitude values. Here is a sample:

```
head(interpTopo)  
  x          y          amplitude  incircle  
0.12925576 -0.6829972 -8.718801     TRUE    
-0.09694182 -0.6829972 -8.916679     TRUE    
-0.06462788 -0.6829972 -9.060801     TRUE  
-0.03231394 -0.6829972 -9.155282     TRUE  
0.00000000 -0.6829972 -9.205160     TRUE  
0.03231394 -0.6829972 -9.215858     TRUE
```

The data frame myData contains several columns with the original data (Condition (A or B), electrode (19 different electrodes) and amplitude of the signal) plus several columns for plotting aims

```
Condition electrode   amplitude chanNo    theta  radius radianTheta  
      A       Fp1 -0.37446309      1  -17.926 0.51499  -0.3128677  
      B       Fp1 -2.31090745      1  -17.926 0.51499  -0.3128677  
      A       Fp2 -1.90578364     34   17.926 0.51499   0.3128677  
      B       Fp2 -0.02573764     34   17.926 0.51499   0.3128677  
      A        F7 -0.16760282      7  -53.913 0.52808  -0.9409594  
      B        F7 -0.25097400      7  -53.913 0.52808  -0.9409594  
      A        F3 -0.45598300      5  -39.947 0.34459  -0.6972067  
      B        F3 -0.57930200      5  -39.947 0.34459  -0.6972067  
      A        F4 -0.25086682     40   39.897 0.34450   0.6963340  
      B        F4 -0.59217445     40   39.897 0.34450   0.6963340  
      A        F8 -0.26977155     42   53.867 0.52807   0.9401565  
      B        F8 -0.39654918     42   53.867 0.52807   0.9401565  
      A        T7  0.85764773     15  -90.000 0.53318  -1.5707963  
      B        T7  1.08665791     15  -90.000 0.53318  -1.5707963  
      A        C3  0.97039173     13  -90.000 0.26669  -1.5707963  
      B        C3  1.65981436     13  -90.000 0.26669  -1.5707963  
      A        C4  1.02980173     50   90.000 0.26667   1.5707963  
      B        C4  1.43448673     50   90.000 0.26667   1.5707963  
      A        T8 -1.06197918     52   90.000 0.53318   1.5707963  
      B        T8 -0.48770773     52   90.000 0.53318   1.5707963  
      A        P7  0.19354909     23 -126.090 0.52808  -2.2006857  
      B        P7  5.44480127     23 -126.090 0.52808  -2.2006857  
      A        P3  1.45094764     21 -140.050 0.34459  -2.4443336  
      B        P3  4.44669364     21 -140.050 0.34459  -2.4443336  
      A        Pz  0.33693382     31  180.000 0.25338   3.1415927  
      B        Pz  1.24227400     31  180.000 0.25338   3.1415927  
      A        P4  1.43877264     58  140.100 0.34450   2.4452063  
      B        P4  3.68937236     58  140.100 0.34450   2.4452063  
      A        P8  0.39259664     60  126.130 0.52807   2.2013838  
      B        P8  4.37601391     60  126.130 0.52807   2.2013838  
      A        O1 -1.44583073     27 -162.070 0.51499  -2.8286551  
      B        O1  3.24404509     27 -162.070 0.51499  -2.8286551  
      A        O2 -2.35238736     64  162.070 0.51499   2.8286551  
      B        O2  2.29718891     64  162.070 0.51499   2.8286551  
      A        Fz  0.13803991     38    0.000 0.25338   0.0000000  
      B        Fz  0.02463536     38    0.000 0.25338   0.0000000  
      A        Cz  0.48804100     48    0.000 0.00000   0.0000000  
      B        Cz  1.60909164     48    0.000 0.00000   0.0000000  
x             y  
  -1.585080e-01  4.899897e-01  
  -1.585080e-01  4.899897e-01  
   1.585080e-01  4.899897e-01  
   1.585080e-01  4.899897e-01  
  -4.267539e-01  3.110460e-01  
  -4.267539e-01  3.110460e-01  
  -2.212539e-01  2.641760e-01  
  -2.212539e-01  2.641760e-01  
  2.209656e-01  2.643000e-01  
  2.209656e-01  2.643000e-01  
  4.264959e-01  3.113826e-01  
  4.264959e-01  3.113826e-01  
 -5.331800e-01  3.264678e-17  
 -5.331800e-01  3.264678e-17  
 -2.666900e-01  1.632951e-17  
 -2.666900e-01  1.632951e-17  
  2.666700e-01  1.632829e-17  
  2.666700e-01  1.632829e-17  
  5.331800e-01  3.264678e-17  
  5.331800e-01  3.264678e-17  
 -4.267376e-01 -3.110683e-01  
 -4.267376e-01 -3.110683e-01  
 -2.212677e-01 -2.641644e-01  
 -2.212677e-01 -2.641644e-01  
  3.102908e-17 -2.533800e-01  
  3.102908e-17 -2.533800e-01  
  2.209794e-01 -2.642884e-01  
  2.209794e-01 -2.642884e-01  
  4.265122e-01 -3.113603e-01  
  4.265122e-01 -3.113603e-01  
 -1.585422e-01 -4.899787e-01  
 -1.585422e-01 -4.899787e-01  
  1.585422e-01 -4.899787e-01  
  1.585422e-01 -4.899787e-01  
  0.000000e+00  2.533800e-01  
  0.000000e+00  2.533800e-01  
  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  
  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
```

Comment: can you add `interpTopo` to the question?

Comment: geom_path and geom_contour understand color, but not fill. Maybe scale_color_gradientn() will get you what you need?

Comment: Can you add data to your question, otherwise it's hard to help you

Comment: thanks  @PoGibas! I added some data to the post. Sorry for not doing it when I posted the question :S. I added only the head of the Interptopo data frame because it has 1601 rows.

Comment: @HarlandMason I've tried your suggestion of replacing scale_fill_gradientn with scale_color_gradientn but I'm still not getting any colours :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: `myData` doesn't have x and y coords

Comment: Sorry again, now the data frame is complete. Thank you!